# Database Log Reuse Wait shows AVAILABILITY_REPLICA but database is no longer part of an availability group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, transaction-log

My database log is growing out of control, I recently removed the database from an availability group by when I look at the log reuse wait description it shows "AVAILABILITY_REPLICA"

I have tried to set the database to simple mode and then shrink the log file, I have tried full backups, log backups (in full mode after a full backup). But the status will not change and I cannot shrink the log file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what version of sql server are you using and what is the patch level ? What do you get from this `select a.*, b.name
from sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states a

LEFT JOIN sys.databases b ON a.database_id = b.database_id` ?

Answer (score 1):

Take your database offline then back online. This should clear the AVAILABILITY_REPLICA wait, then you can shrink whatever you need to shrink.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when you delete a database from the AG, and even delete the AG, a database will still stay in AVAILABILITY_REPLICA wait mode. (At least in 2019 without cumulative updates).

A restart of the SQL service solves it.